# Expectation Optimization

Tags: probability

You have $\$1.50$ and are given the opportunity to risk any portion of the $\$1.50$. This  portion you risk has a chance of one in ten to return $10$ times the value. How much should you risk if any to achieve maximum expectation.

Comment: Hint:  if it is a winning bet, you want as much as you can get.  If it is a losing bet, you don't want any part of it.